# Using bundle for message passing in sliding tab fragments returns null

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, sliding

I am new at using fragments. This is how I am passing StringArrayList inside bundle in the onActivityCreated of first fragment in sliding tab

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    next_personal = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.personal_next);


    next_personal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            validate();
        }
    });
}

private void validate() {

    isValid = FormValidator.validate(this, new SimpleErrorPopupCallback(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), true));

    if (isValid) {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add(memID.getText().toString());
        arrayList.add(idNumber.getText().toString());
        arrayList.add(firstName.getText().toString());
        arrayList.add(secondName.getText().toString());
        arrayList.add(lastName.getText().toString());
        arrayList.add(secondLastName.getText().toString());

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("personal",arrayList);
        Log.d("bundle",": "+bundle.toString());
        FragContactInfo frag = new FragContactInfo();
        frag.setArguments(bundle);

        ((RegisterTabActivity) getActivity()).setCurrentItem(1, true);
    }
}
```

And then I am trying to get the ArrayList in the third fragment of sliding tab as below:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("personal")) {
        ArrayList<String> userId = bundle.getStringArrayList("personal");
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Bundle is null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It keeps on returning null. Did the same inside onCreateView of both fragments, same result. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Are you using the same activity for all your fragments? and where you add the fragements to your activity? i guess you're not using the same instance of the fragment. Please post the activity code.

Comment: I resolved it by creating a custom method in target fragment which accepts arraylist and called the method from the message sending fragment. The fragments are for sliding tab. So yes, same parent activity for all tab fragments. Thank you for responding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bundle did not help in parsing data between fragments (Somehow)

So I simply created method to set and get data in target fragment.

```
public void setPdata(JSONObject obj) {
    this.personalJSON = obj;
}

public JSONObject getPdata() {
    return personalJSON;
}
```

Then I called the set method to set json in sender fragment.

```
FragContactInfo frag = new FragContactInfo();
        frag.setPdata(json);
```

And then access the json by simply calling get method.

```
array1 = getPdata().getJSONArray("args");
```

If anyone has a more productive solution, please do tell. Happy Coding.